# Kubuntu has screen tearing when rotating the screen

Tags: kde, screen, tearing, rotate

I've been using Kubuntu 20.4 LTS on my HP Elitebook x360 1030 g5 with barely any issue. As the laptop can convert into a tablet, when I rotate the screen, there is screen tearing when moving windows, browsing the internet, watching videos. This only happens when rotating the screen. I suspect it might have something to do with Fractional Scaling (set at 1.25), but it doesn't have the tearing when using the screen the normal way. I also tried the newest Kubuntu 22.04 and seems to have the same issue still. Any thoughts?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. It's definitely not a setting-- who would want that?  I suggest that you [report it](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121). Bugs are more likely when using uncommon hardware, like yours.  The majority of devices running Ubuntu don't have a screen that rotates when you turn it.  Reporting a bug will alert devs to the issue so they can work on a fix.  Devs can't fix issues they don't know about.  In the meantime consider switching between X.org and Wayland. Also consider disabling fractional scaling if the problem doesn't happen with it off.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will report the bug soon. I can't use the scaling at 100% because everything is too small. Wayland on kde behaves buggy like fractional scaling looks blurry and other issues.

Comment: Unless you have a very high (>400) ppi display, fractional scaling will always appear blurry compared to without scaling (except for 200%). If you happen to have a 1080p or lower display, fractional scaling at 125% is going to look quite bad. That's because you can't scale pixels evenly at 125%, which is why it's called *fractional* scaling. In the case of a medium or low ppi display, you are better off tweaking the size of fonts and title bars, which happens to be easy to do in KDE. Other problems, like flickering and tearing, are probably bugs and should be reported.